# Converting some VB.NET code to C# - Need Advice

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working with the original MMO that ever opened called VZones and they have a dll file that allows you to call the functions from this dll to do certain things within the program.

I have found some VB.NET code and the problem I am having is converting it to a way that will work with C# (using VS 2017)

You setup the DLL calls with this, which works fine:

```
[DllImport("vzdapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern string DapiGetText(string BufferIn, int LengthIn, int Timeout);
```

The problem is I need to convert this VB.NET code that is from someone else to what will work in C#. I have tried a few different options but the program just closes and never gives me an error.

```
object obj1 = (object)new string(char.MinValue, 32678);
vzText.Text = this.DapiGetText(Conversions.ToString(obj1), Strings.Len(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(obj1)), 1500);
```

The problem arises in the Conversions.ToString part, which I have of course tried to just make obj1.ToString() and that may work fine but the place I think is getting caught up is when it tries to run the middle code "Strings.Len(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(obj1))".

Does anyone have any help into getting this into something that will work in C#? Thanks!

Comment: From [Strings.Len Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez71k3ay(v=vs.110).aspx) *the Len function returns the size as it will be written to the file by the FilePut function.* So it's basically getting the length. In c# all you have to do is convert `ToString()` then call `Length`  property. Did you tried that ?

Comment: Add a refernce to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` for the `RunTimeHelpers` class

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm missing, but why do you need to cast the `string` as `object` on the first place? `string str1 = new string(char.MinValue, 32678);` and `vzText.Text = this.DapiGetText(str1, str1.Length, 1500);`

Comment: You need to first fix the C# declaration, it has a very nasty bug.  Unfortunately it does not blow up a program often enough.  The first argument must be StringBuilder, not string.  Necessary because string is immutable and this function wants to modify the string.  The proper way to call it is to first use the StringBuilder(int) constructor to create the string buffer, using a value large enough to fit the expected returned string.  Pass its Capacity as the second argument.  ToString() after the call.

Comment: Where's the VB code?  It would make this much easier.

Comment: It sounds like you're just guessing where the problem is. Maybe you should try split your operations to different lines to make debugging easier.

Comment: "I have found some VB.NET code" - I think you mean that you decompiled an assembly generated from the VB compiler as I seriously doubt anyone ever wrote the code `Strings.Len(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(obj1))` in the original program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm wondering if the conversions are necessary as the initial object you define is already a string, try the following solution:

```
string obj = new string(char.MinValue, Int16.MaxValue);
vzText.Text = this.DapiGetText(obj, obj.Length, 1500);
```

Comment: This answer along with one above basically gave way to the output below, which works just fine now, so thanks!

string str1 = new string(char.MinValue, 32678);
VZText.Text = DapiGetText(str1, str1.Length, 1000);